# command to check if directory size is greater than 1g

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I am looking for a command (Windows or Linux) that calculates the directory size and returns true or 0 if the directory size is greater than 1gb.

If less than 1gb returns 1 or false.

Powershell command also appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux works like this are made with *the might* [du](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du).
It exists a [du.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651.aspx) for windows downloadable from the microsoft technet.

On many places on the net you can find examples of powershell scripts that you can easily modify for your purpose, such the [following one](http://nickbeare.com/du.html):

```
$startFolder = Read-Host "Enter directory"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)

"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
```

In the [original reference](http://nickbeare.com/du.html) there is a longer e more complex script that returns the values for each entry. Over there you can put a filter on the size over the desired value.
Read too the [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d7661ab5-6bec-402e-a888-6848c450098b/disk-usage-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/868290/3569208) on stackexchange...
or google for *windows equivalent of du*.